# Timer in program gets shorter every time

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm trying to make a timer so after the GIF is over it is replaced with a solid frame so it appears that the GIF ends. It works, but for some reason the timer gets shorter and shorter. (The reason is probably obvious but I have a poor understanding of timers).

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {
int sum = 0;
int deaths = 0;
JTextField devs;
JButton a;
ImageIcon guncold;
ImageIcon gunactive;

public Gui() {
    super("Russian Roulette");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Font f = new Font("Western", 20, 20);

    guncold = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("guncold.gif"));
    gunactive = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("gunfiring.gif"));
    a = new JButton(guncold);
    a.setToolTipText("Click To Play");

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

    final JTextField display = new JTextField("Click Gun To Play!", 12);

    devs = new JTextField("Deaths: " + deaths, 10);
    devs.setEditable(false);
    devs.setFont(f);
    devs.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    devs.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    p.add(a);
    p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    p1.add(devs);
    p1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    p2.add(display);
    p2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    display.setFont(f);
    display.setEditable(false);
    display.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    display.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int rand = r.nextInt(5);
            switch (rand) {
            case 0:
                display.setText("Bang! You're dead.");
                deaths++;
                devs.setText("Deaths: " + deaths);
                break;
            case 1:
                display.setText("You're alive!");
                break;
            case 2:
                display.setText("You're alive!");
                break;
            case 3:
                display.setText("You're alive!");
                break;
            case 4:
                display.setText("You're alive!");
                break;
            case 5:
                display.setText("You're alive!");
                break;
            }
            Timer t = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener()); 
            if (rand == 0) {
                t.start();
                a.setIcon(gunactive);
                t.restart();    
                } else {
                a.setIcon(guncold);
            }

        }

    });
}

private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        a.setIcon(guncold);

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a time with each action. Create the timer once and restart it when an action was performed.

This line:

```
Timer t = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener());
```

Should be outside of `actionpPerformed`.

You can use something like this:

```
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
    private JButton button;
    public MyListener(JButton button){
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.button.setIcon(guncold);
    }
}
```

And now that you have a reference to the button whose image you're changing, pass the reference on construction:

```
add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
// HERE
Timer t = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener(a)); 
a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int rand = r.nextInt(5);
        switch (rand) {
        // ... code
        if (rand == 0) {
            t.restart();    
        } else {
            a.setIcon(guncold);
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Okay, this took me a moment to reconcile, yes, you're right, but you've missed the opportunity to highlight "why" - Each `Timer` which is started, repeats.  You could also use `Timer#setRepeats` and pass it `false`, which you'd need to do for a global `Timer` as well ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks that fixed it! Also thanks Reut Sharabani!

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's possible I've missed the point since I don't understand what you're saying. Why would you need to make the global timer none-repeating if you're restarting it? I expect the game to end once you're dead

Comment: Not the op ;) in either case, you need to either stop the Timer or set it to not repeating. You've pinpointed the problem, but, me, missed the opportunity to explain why it was occurring, creating multiple Timers was just part of the problem ;)

Comment: Even if the Timer objects were none-repeating, they'd end and set the image to whatever means the game has ended. So basically even then it won't perform as expected. Is that right?

Comment: @ReutSharabani No they wouldn't, they keep ticking unless you stopped them or made them non-repeating, which is why, creating a new Timer each time, made it appear as if time was reducing, cause they had multiple Timers all running at different times ;). As I understand it, the op wants to set the icon of the label after a given period of time, not repeatedly ;)

Comment: Let's say you start the first Timer, it ticks every 1 second, now you start the second Timer (and by some fluke get it to start halfway through the first), the first timer will tick before the first, making appear as if the time has been reduced by half, add a third and forth and suddenly you have a situation where the the image is never been allowed to play because one of the many timers is changing the state of the image back to its still state, repeatedly ;)

Comment: Okay, that's actually what I was saying. just that English isn't my best language :)